# Python dictionary and list inside Class update and append

Tags: python, list, class, dictionary

I have this problem that is very annoying and don't know why happens.
I have this class:

```
class Person:
my_dict = {}
my_list = []
... other attributes

...


def add_dic(self, key, val):
    self.my_dict.update({key: val})

def add_to_list(self, i):
    self.my_list.append(i)
```

When I create this:

```
person1 = Person('name1')
person2 = Person('name2')

person1.add_dic(1,2)
person2.add_dic(3,4)

print person1.my_dict

#{1:2, 3:4}   when to me it should be {1:2}
```

Why person1 get updated with updates of person2? The same problem happens with updates in person1 that affects to person2. The same problem when appending the list.

How to solve this to get updates separately? Maybe there is a Python concept that is not clear to me.

What solution can be to append or update but inside the class? not creating a temporal variable and then updating that variable and writing to the dictionary or list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created class variables instead of instance ones. Check this: [Instance vs Class Variables](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)

Comment: Now I see my error... The problem for me is that I thought it was like in Java that you put all the attributes outside. But actually in Python the attributes should go inside the constructor. Cool. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What is in your `__init__()`

Currently
`my_dict = {}` and `my_list = []` are shared between the whole class

If you add

```
def __init__(self, name):
    self.my_dict = {};
```

Then it should solve the problem